# Pushed over someone else yanked gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have just built gem and I give it version `0.0.1`.
When I checked [my gem on rubygem.org](https://rubygems.org/gems/text_analyzer) I saw it has 1 version listed that it's not mine.
I checked [all versions](https://rubygems.org/gems/text_analyzer/versions) and I saw that my gem was yanked. It has wrong version `0.2.0`too. I guess it is kind of bug that shows my gem as yanked instead of older one.
I read that if someone yank all gems I can own that name so it installed with normal command `gem install text_analyzer` and It worked as expected but it only shows this message after installation:

`WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:

      json (>= 0)

WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.

Please report a bug if this causes problems.

Gem 'text_analyzer' installed.`

How can I mark other gem as 'not mine'?
For next version, what version should I put? I think both gems are with version `0.0.1` but bug(?) shows version `0.2.0` too. So is this reasonable to start with `0.3.0` or `1.0.0`?

Comment: You should probably report this here: https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems.org/issues

Answer (score 1):

This isn't bug but a side effect of another programmer yanking a version (0.2.0 in this case) of a gem with the same name as yours. Yanked versions are consumed and can't be used later on.

See http://help.rubygems.org/kb/gemcutter/removing-a-published-rubygem for more details.

> **Why can't I repush a gem version?**
>
> This causes several problems to start happening:
>
> - Mirrors that comb the site (with gem mirror) would be out of sync.
> - Clients can't verify the contents of gems (via MD5 or something similar) so they could download different versions, expecting the same code.
> - You're not going to run out of gem versions, just push a new one.

Comment: So, I should just use version bigger than `0.2.0`[`0.3.0`/`1.0.0`]? Am I right?

Comment: Well, you can use whatever versions you want. You won't be able to push versions that has been yanked. Keep that mind.